# In Android how to exclude the status bar from the animation

Tags: android, animation

I have an app with an animation for the transitions of activities. The activities enter from the bottom.
I have the following functions:

```
fun Context.startActivityAnimated(intent: Intent) {
  val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(
    this,
    anim.start_animation,
    anim.start_animation_outgoing,
  ).toBundle()
  startActivity(intent, options)
}
```

I need to exclude the status bar from being animated or I need to hide the status bar before starting the animation and show it at the end.

Is it possible to do it? Please notice that I'm using `makeCustomAnimation` and not `makeSceneTransitionAnimation`.